# Faster way to create many filters in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

What is the fastest way to create a message filter in Thunderbird?

I started sorting mail via filters, and I have to create 10+ filters a day. I was unable to find a way to (for example) right-click on the folder and then to create a new message filter for that folder.

The fastest way I found is selecting a message, then *Message* -> *Create filter from message*. I wasn't able to find any add-on which could facilitate this.

Comment: You may be able to use a message filter import/export extension. With one you might be able to hand code filters and then import them into TB. Here's a link to [one](https://en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com/en-US/thunderbird/addon/thunderbird-message-filter-imp/?src=ss) I found.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [install my addon quickFilters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfilters/). You can set it up to start up automatically and suggest adding a new filter whenever you move an email. It also prefills the filter action and conditions depending on a selected template. I guarantee this is the fastest way to create new filters. (drag-click-click or click-click-click if the mail was already moved to the new location).